# Adding elements into arrays held as values in a map

Tags: javascript, maps

I really struggle with the following. I have a simple Map, where for each key there is a value, which is an array.

```
MyMap= {
'Anna' => [ 'Item1', 'Item2' ]
}
```

However, I would need to extend the arrays for particular keys, i.e. add elements to them, but just cannot figure out the syntax.

I tried

```
 myMap.set(name,myMap.get(name).push(item))
```

Comment: Note that [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array and not the array itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not have to set again. [Map holds a reference to the original array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get#using_get_to_retrieve_a_reference_to_an_object) and when you push it modifies the array

```js
const map = new Map();

map.set('Anna', ['Item1','Item2']);
console.log(...map)

map.get('Anna').push('Item3')
console.log(...map)
```